# Validation of new password does not work

Tags: angular, validation

I have a form for changing password:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="newPassword">New Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" formControlName="newPassword">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="newPassword.touched && newPassword.invalid">
           <div *ngIf="newPassword.errors.required">  New password is required </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="from-group">
        <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm New Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" formControlName="confirmPassword">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="confirmPassword.touched && confirmPassword.invalid">
            <div *ngIf="confirmPassword.errors.required">  New password is required </div>           
         </div>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="form.invalid &&  form.errors.PasswordsNotMatch">Passwords do not mach</div>
    </div>  

    <button class="btn btn-primary">Change Password</button>
```

TS file:

```
form = new FormGroup({
    oldPassword : new FormControl('', [Validators.required], PasswordValidators.validOldPassword),
    newPassword : new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    confirmPassword : new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  }, PasswordValidators.PasswordsNotMatch);

  get oldPassword () {
    return this.form.get ('oldPassword');
  }

  get newPassword () {
    return this.form.get ('newPassword');
  }

  get confirmPassword () {
    return this.form.get ('confirmPassword');
  }
```

And the code for validating new password is implemented in a separate file:

```
export class PasswordValidators {

    static PasswordsNotMatch (control: AbstractControl) {
        let newPassword = control.get('newPassword');
        let confirmPassword = control.get ('confirmPassword');

        if (newPassword.value != confirmPassword.value)
            return { PasswordsNotMatch : true };
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is the error I get on my console: `Cannot read property 'PasswordsNotMatch' of null`

Can you help me finding out what is wrong in my code?

Comment: Did you import PasswordValidator?

Comment: Yes, it is already imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the provided code:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="form.invalid &&  form.errors.PasswordsNotMatch">Passwords do not mach</div>
```

You're trying to access the errors property of your FormGroup. This property is null if you don't have any error (https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#errors)

You should add a condition to test if your form has a non null errors property

```
*ngIf="form.invalid && form.errors && form.errors.PasswordsNotMatch"
```